# Excel VBA to select a cell address found with Find()

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on excel forecasting workbook - I have a bulk data sheet which contains data for all products, and a detail sheet where the user selects a particular product from a drop down.  For each product I want the user to review the data on the detail sheet, and enter a manual forecast if required.  I then want the user to be trigger a macro which will copy and paste this manual forecast into the relevant cells on the bulk data sheet.  The copy / paste bits are fine, but I am struggling with selecting the relevant cell to paste into - I have the following code which locates the correct cell, but rather than displaying a MsgBox with the cell address I want excel to select that cell address

```
Sub Findrow()   
   Dim Fnd As Range   
   Set Fnd = Sheets("FORECAST_MODEL").Range("B:B").Find(Sheets("DETAIL_SHEET").Range("B2").Value, , , xlWhole, , , False, , False)
   If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
      Set Fnd = Fnd.Offset(-1, 25)
      MsgBox Fnd.Address
   End If
End Sub
```

Any help gratefully received

Thanks

Comment: `Fnd.Select` should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fnd.Select` instead of `MsgBox Fnd.Address`

---

Or even the whole code here:

```
If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
   Set fnd = fnd.Offset(-1, 25)
   MsgBox fnd.Address
End If
```

can be replaced with 1 line:

```
If Not fnt Is Nothing Then fnd.Offset(-1, 25).Select
```

Comment: Either method is giving me a run time error 1004 - Select method of Range class failed - any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisM - I guess your worksheet is protected with a password?

Comment: No passwords - the only thing I can think is that I need to move sheet - i.e. the macro is being run from DETAIL_SHEET but is finding a location on FORECAST_MODEL - I'm guessing the macro needs to select the correct sheet before selecting the cell address that has been found

Comment: @ChrisM - `Sheets("FORECAST_MODEL").Select` before the `Fnd.Select`

Comment: Jackpot!  Thanks very much for the help @Vityata

Comment: @ChrisM - Yuhuu! :)